# AspectJ (annotations) compile-time weave with Ant and NetBeans

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans, ant, aspectj

I want to use **compile-time AspectJ with Ant in NetBeans**. I want to run it on Google App Engine, but it is not essential at the moment. AspectJ is annotation based. 
I prefer compile-time weave (modification, instrumentation? of classes). I wouldn't like to use a custom classloader. How to achieve this?

### What I already have:

I tried [AspectJ Annotation Tutorial](http://www.andrewewhite.net/wordpress/2010/03/17/aspectj-annotation-tutorial/) with NetBeans. I modified build.xml to process aspectj (using [iajc Ant task](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/antTasks-iajc.html)) as described [here](http://includeblogh.blogspot.com/2011/04/install-aspectj-in-netbeans-691.html). The problem is that it requires adding `-javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver.jar` (*it is not possible on GAE*). 
Running my build generates this output:

```
info compiling C:\NetBeansProjects\TryAspectJ\src\net\andrewewhite\examples\HelloWorld.java
weaveinfo Join point 'method-call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String))' in Type 'net.andrewewhite.examples.HelloWorld' (HelloWorld.java:9) advised by before advice from 'net.andrewewhite.aspects.BasicAspect' (BasicAspect.class:17(from BasicAspect.java))
weaveinfo Join point 'method-call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String))' in Type 'net.andrewewhite.examples.HelloWorld' (HelloWorld.java:9) advised by after advice from 'net.andrewewhite.aspects.BasicAspect' (BasicAspect.class:23(from BasicAspect.java))
info woven class net.andrewewhite.examples.HelloWorld (from C:\NetBeansProjects\TryAspectJ\src\net\andrewewhite\examples\HelloWorld.java)
info Compiler took 2547ms
```

When I run my project with `-javaagent` parameter it works OK. (In NetBeans: Click on project>Properties>Run>VM Options: -javaagent:./dist/lib/aspectjweaver.jar). Otput for code from [tutorial](http://www.andrewewhite.net/wordpress/2010/03/17/aspectj-annotation-tutorial/):

```
run:
About to make call to print Hello World
Hello World!
Just made call to print Hello World
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Without agent (VM Options cleared) code runs as if it was without AspectJ:

```
run:
Hello World!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

### Sources:

\TryAspectJ\src\META-INF\aop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="net.andrewewhite.aspects.BasicAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

\TryAspectJ\src\net\andrewewhite\aspects\BasicAspect.java

```
package net.andrewewhite.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class BasicAspect {

    @Before("   call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String)) " +
            "&& !within(net.andrewewhite.aspects..*)")
    public void beforePrintlnCall() {
        System.out.println("About to make call to print Hello World");
    }

    @After("    call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String)) " +
           "&&  !within(net.andrewewhite.aspects..*)")
    public void afterPrintlnCall() {
        System.out.println("Just made call to print Hello World");
    }
}
```

\TryAspectJ\src\net\andrewewhite\examples\HelloWorld.java

```
package net.andrewewhite.examples;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
    }   
}
```

\TryAspectJ\build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TryAspectJ" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project TryAspectJ.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>        
<taskdef classpath="lib/aspectj/aspectjtools.jar" resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties"/>         

    <target name="aspectj">
        <echo level="info">--- aspectj (start) ---</echo>
        <iajc destDir="${build.classes.dir}" source="1.6" target="1.6" showweaveinfo="true" verbose="true" >
            <inpath>
                <pathelement location="lib/aspectj/aspectjrt.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}" /> 
            </inpath>
            <sourceroots>
                <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
            </sourceroots>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${javac.classpath}"/>
                <pathelement location="${j2ee.platform.classpath}"/>
            </classpath>
        </iajc> 
         <echo level="info">--- aspectj finished ---</echo>
    </target>

<target name="-post-compile" depends="aspectj"></target>
</project>
```

**What do I have to add or change?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution. 
This is the correct build.xml fragment:

```
<taskdef classpath="lib/aspectjtools.jar" resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties"/>
<target name="aspectj">
    <echo level="info">--- aspectj (start) ---</echo>
    <!-- begin fix classpath for this bug https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40291 -->
    <condition property="targetos" value="windows" else="unix">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>
    <!-- converting classpath -->
    <pathconvert targetos="${targetos}" property="javac.convertedClasspath" >
        <path path="${javac.classpath}" />                   
    </pathconvert>
    <!-- end fix classpath -->
    <iajc source="1.6" target="1.6" showweaveinfo="true" verbose="true" destdir="${build.classes.dir}"  >
        <inpath>
            <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>    
        </inpath>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${javac.convertedClasspath}" />
        </classpath>
    </iajc>
    <echo level="info">--- aspectj (finished) ---</echo>
</target>
<target name="-post-compile" depends="aspectj"></target>
```

Calling `java -classpath ./lib/aspectjrt.jar -jar TryAspectJ.jar` works OK. What is strange is that from NetBeans (Right clik on project->Run) results are as if they were without AspectJ. I think that NetBeans runs projects from `build/classes` dir not as jar. But it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an aspect path element as a subelement to the iajc element.

```
<aspectpath>
    <pathelement location="..." />
</aspectpath>
```

The `aop.xml` file is only necessary for AspectJ load-time weaving.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added <aspectpath><pathelement location="${dist.jar}" /></aspectpath>. When called from <target name="-post-compile" depends="aspectj"></target> I get "warning build config error: skipping missing, empty or corrupt aspectpath entry: C:\NetBeansProjects\TryAspectJ\dist\TryAspectJ.jar". When called from <target name="-post-jar" depends="aspectj"></target> warning is gone, but the result is same as if it was without <aspectpath>. Here is a detailed compilation log: http://zacheusz.eu/java/various/aspectj02.log